# Question about norm of ideals of some ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, normed-spaces, extension-field

I want to understand the proof of the theorem below and everything written in *italic* is my comments about some statements that are not clear for me. So, if you clarify  the parts that I wrote in italic and if its possible give another proof, I would appreciate it.

> **Theorem.** Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. Then,
>
> **i**.We have that $N(\alpha\mathcal{O})=|N_{K/ \mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|, \alpha\in\mathcal{O}$.
>
> **ii**.The norm of $I$ is finite.
>
> **Proof.**
>
> **i**.$\mathcal{O}$ is a free Abelian group of rank $n= [K:\mathbb{Q}]$, thus, there exist a $\mathbb{Z}-$basis $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ of $\mathcal{O}$ such that $\mathcal{O}=\alpha_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus\dots\ \oplus\alpha_n\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> -*Now, how can we write $\mathcal{O}=\alpha_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus\dots\ \oplus\alpha_n\mathbb{Z}$? I was thinking that we can write $\mathcal{O}= \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}R$ where $R$ is some $\mathbb{Z}-$module so the summands would be the same.*
>
> Then, it is a general result(how?) on free Abelian groups that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, both of same rank with $\mathbb{Z}$-bases $x_1, \dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ respectively with $y_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j}a_{ij}x_j$, then $|G/H|=|det(a_{ij})|$.
>
> -*I have no idea about how to prove this 'general' result. I have found some questions related to this result but it would be great if you can clarify it.*
>
> We apply this theorem in our case where $G=\mathcal{O}$ and $H=\alpha\mathcal{O}$. Since one basis is obtained from the other by multiplication by $\alpha$, we have that $|\mathcal{O}/ \alpha\mathcal{O}|=det(\mu_\alpha)=|N_{K/ \mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|.$
>
> *Is $\mu_\alpha$ the transformation matrix of the linear operator-field homomorphism- $\varphi : K \to \mathbb{C}$ where $\varphi(x) = \alpha x$?*
>
> **ii.** Let $0 \neq \alpha \in I$. Since $I$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ and $\alpha \mathcal{O} \subset I$, we have a surjective map $\mathcal{O}/ \alpha \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O} / I$. So, the result follows from part one.
>
> *Do we define the map as $\varphi(x + \alpha\mathcal{O})=x+I$, and how did we conclude the result?*

Comment: About $|G/H|=|det(a_{ij})|$: Use the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should clarify what you need here

- $\mathcal{O}_K=\{ \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \alpha_j , c_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a rank-$n$ free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (or free abelian group), which means we have the isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
  $$\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathcal{O}_K,\qquad \varphi(c) =\sum_{j=1}^n c_j \alpha_j$$
- We didn't define the multiplication in $\mathcal{O}_K$ (ie. the result of $\alpha_i\alpha_j$). All we need to know is that the multiplication by any $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ is given by some matrix $B \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ :
  $$\beta \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \alpha_j = \beta\varphi(c) = \varphi(B c)=\sum_{j=1}^n (Bc)_j \alpha_j$$
- And from the $\mathbb{Z}^n$ side we have the quotient of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules formula
  $$|\mathcal{O}_K/\beta\mathcal{O}_K|=|\varphi^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_K)/\varphi^{-1}(\beta\mathcal{O}_K)| = |\mathbb{Z}^n/B\mathbb{Z}^n| = |\det(B)| = |N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\beta)|$$

  Note how changing the basis $\alpha_j$ by another one means replacing $B$ by $M B M^{-1}$ with $M,M^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ and hence $|\det(M)| = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am thinking about it and I would like to ask how could we write the last formula :$ |\mathcal{O}_K / \beta \mathcal{O}_K  |= \dots?$

Comment: @Ninja with $\varphi^{-1}$, I edited a little. As I wrote, the main point is that $\mathcal{O}_K / \beta \mathcal{O}_K$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, no need to define the full multiplication in $ \mathcal{O}_K$, all we need to know is that $\beta$ acts as an integer matrix on the $c_j$

Comment: @Ninja And (up to a change of basis) this matrix $B$ is exactly the one we used for defining $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\beta)$